# how can i iterate a for loop for every seven days

Tags: perl

How can i write a for loop in perl that should execute a block of statements every week.
For example: Begin Time is: 00:00:00 Monday, then again the loop should iterate at 00:00:00 Monday next week.

Thanks for any input.

Regards,
Chandu

Comment: Don't use perl, use `cron`.

Answer (score 2):

`cron` (or whatever other task scheduler your operating system uses) is the correct tool for this, not Perl.

However, in the simplest case, this can be done in Perl with `sleep 604800;`, which will wait 604,800 seconds (i.e., 7 days) before proceeding to the next statement.  No loops are required.

Comment: Actually i'm writing a perl based CGI so on a weekly basis the statements inside the for loop must be executed...

Comment: Are you sure you want a CGI script to run for such a long time? It sounds as if you want to write a daemon. But for periodic tasks a scheduler is probably the best solution.

Comment: Odds are, you probably _can't_ write a CGI that runs for that long because the web server will decide that the request has timed out and kill the script in much less than a week. (Apache defaults to 5 minutes.) If the operations need to be triggered from CGI, then your best bet is to schedule a task in cron on some other machine (such as your workstation) which calls the CGI's URL each week, with the CGI running the commands and then exiting as soon as it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can make a timer that runs over a week. It is not related on day of week, but you can start it on Monday and it will be started again on next Monday.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday tv_interval usleep); 
# 1 week equal 168 hr
for(;;) {
    # put your codes here
    # ...

    for my $h (0..167) {
        for my $m (0..59) {
            for my $s (0..59) {
                for my $ms (0..999) {
                    print "$h:$m:$s:$ms\n";
                    usleep(1000);
                    $ms += 0.001;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is in fact a timer, then you can see in which day you are or how much time left...